# How to control the classpath when running or debugging an IntelliJ plugin from IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am trying to develop an IntelliJ plugin. In doing so, I have a project containing two modules and some transitive dependencies:

```
 myplugin
     |
     V
 mylibrary
  |     |
  V     V
dep1   dep2 ...
```

When I try to execute the plugin via a `Plugin` runtime configuration, IDEA can find classes in `myplugin` and `mylibrary`, but it cannot find classes in the transitive dependencies, preferring instead to throw `NoClassDefFoundError`s when they are accessed.

The runtime configuration is correctly set up to "use classpath of module" `myplugin`.

Further investigation shows that the process spawned to execute the plugin has the following classpath:

```
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/idea.jar:
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/resources_en.jar:
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/annotations.jar:
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/log4j.jar:
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/oromatcher.jar:
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/util.jar:
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/trove4j.jar:
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/picocontainer.jar:
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/jdom.jar:
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/jna.jar:
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/jna-utils.jar:
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/openapi.jar:
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/extensions.jar:
/Users/me/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea14/plugins-sandbox/plugins/myplugin/lib/myplugin.jar
```

... so the only classpath element containing my code is the last one. Un-jarring this shows that the JAR contains classes from `myplugin` and `mylibrary`, but no classes from the transitive dependencies. Therefore IDEA appears to be cleverly bundling up individual classes to build a plugin JAR, but uncleverly failing to respect the entire classpath.

Is there a way that I can control this? If not, is there another way of testing plugins that contain transitive dependencies in this way? What will happen when IDEA finally creates the plugin JAR- will it forget to add classes from the transitive dependencies then?

Comment: Are the dependencies from mylibrary on dep1/dep2 marked as exported in the project structure dialog? If they aren't, please try marking them as such.

Comment: Yes, I had already marked the dependencies from `mylibrary` to `dep1` and `dep2` as exported.

Comment: Did you fix this?